# Using FINDSTR to search for a pattern and assign it to a variable

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command, dos

I have the following entry in the file Build.aip. I need to write a batch file that searches for "PackageFileName and prints the value assigned for that in the file. In this case, I need to print MyPackageName on the console:

```
<ROW BuildKey="DefaultBuild" BuildName="DefaultBuild" BuildOrder="1" BuildType="0" PackageFolder="C:\Build\Build.aip" PackageFileName="MyPackageName" Languages="en" InstallationType="4">
```

May you please give me some examples how I can do that? I seen in some forums that this can be done using FINDSTR.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findstr "PackageFileName" Build.aip

If you want to make it case insensitive, add the /i argument.

For more details, type findstr /?

Updated for an example to use the for statement

```
FOR /F "token=2" %i in (`FINDSTR "PackageFileName" Build.aip`) do SET var=%i
```

A couple things to keep in mind here:

- This version is based on Windows 8.1; it may work differently in different versions of Windows.
- The token=2 is an example assuming that the word you are looking for is the second word in the line
- If PackageFileName appears more than once in Build.aip, this code will break.
- The findstring command is surrounded by back-ticks, not single quotes.
- I haven't tested it; the SET may not actually survive the for loop. So test!
- If you use it in a batch file, you must double all the % signs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will give full line as output. I want to extract only MyPackageName and assign it to a variable. Is there a way to do that? I have very little knowledge in batch.

Comment: Yes, probably. Your question doesn't include information about the format of the Build.aip file. Generally, though, you are probably going to look for the FOR command. It has some truly bizarre options, including being able to run another command, parsing out lines, and executing commands.

Comment: May you please give me a sample example on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just saw that you added the line from the Build.aip file. You will probably need multiple nested for statements with different options and different delimiters. You may want to look into using PowerShell; this kind of more advanced complex scripting is often easier to do in PowerShell.